# Absolute positioning always below parent's siblings

Tags: css

I'm trying to visualize an animation. I had a strange problem that absolute positioning doesn't make my div the top one.
Simply I have, a container and a series of div and a single child for each.

```
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner1"> <!-- this is relative -->
    <div class="inner2"></div> <!-- this is absolute with z-index 1000  (1)-->
  </div>
  <div class="inner1"> <!-- this is relative (2) -->
    <div class="inner2"></div> <!-- this is absolute -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is `(2)`  under the `(1)`

Please check the fiddle to understand my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/MSpVM/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see from your fiddle, you don't actually have `.inner2` absolutely positioned, and you are currently moving it right using a left-margin.

If you add `position: absolute` to the CSS rules of `.inner2` this seems to fix the problem.

You might also be interested in reading this article about [CSS transition/transform performance](http://css-tricks.com/tale-of-animation-performance/) (I noticed your using CSS to transition the `.inner2` elements)

Comment: Wow, how did I do such a silly mistake. I added ``position:absolute`` rule to the wrong elements. Thanks.